# Flow of electrons in wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electricity, electrons

If we apply potential difference through wire we know that there is an electric current which is the flow of electrons.I want to know how do electrons move do they move within wire like in the picture below or do they move only through its surface? . If it moves only through its surface why is there n which is number of electrons per cubic meter in I=qnav. All the pictures i have seen on the internet shows it in a way that electrons move in wire too. But some people I conversed with told me it only moves through its surface because there is no net electric field inside conductor.(isn't this applied on electrostatics when electrons don't move)
[image]

Answer (score 10):

The answer depends on the level of approximation that you are confortable with. Are we discussing a pinball like model for electrons or a quantum mechanical model? Do we consider the electrons independent or do we include interactions? Do we care about the lattice structure? Do we care about phonons? Do we care about the details of the surface? These problems define a whole area of research called solid state physics.

Under Drude model (no lattice, no magnetic effects, electrons do not interact, electrons deflect randomly from time to time from defects in the material, electrons behaviour is simulated as pin-ball balls) the electrons under a DC voltage fly through the material homogeneously and your formula is a good as it gets .

Only when the voltage changes periodically (AC), you get the skin effect (the effect that current travels only near the surface, extra assumptions required).

Answer (score 3):

You were right. The electric field is zero for a conductor in equilibrium only.

At low frequencies such as DC the current is happening throughout the cross section A. When a voltage is applied there is a field$E=V/l$ and a current density $J=I/A=\sigma E$ with [conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity) $\sigma$.

For AC voltages '[the current density is largest near the surface of the conductor and decreases exponentially with greater depths in the conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)'.